# How Do I Customise The Corda Hospital?

Tags: corda

As you can see from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815369/how-do-i-handle-hospital-exceptions-from-my-api) a flow is being sent to the hospital when a unique db constraint is being violated

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation:
```

This is clearly never going to be able to be resolved so I want it to fail instead and not go to the hospital.

It is currently going to the hospital due to Cordas built-in rules.

Is it possible to modify these rules to prevent this exception from being sent to the hospital?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to [the official documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-flow-hospital.html#run-time-behaviour); this type of errors will go to the flow hospital:

> Database constraint violation (ConstraintViolationException): This scenario may occur due to natural contention between racing flows as Corda delegates handling using the database’s optimistic concurrency control. If this exception occurs, the flow will retry. After retrying a number of times, the errored flow is kept in for observation.

So you have 2 things that you can do:

1. Go to the database and modify the existing record that's colliding with the record the flow is trying to add.
2. Go to your node's terminal and kill the flow.

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, 1) It is a unique constraint. It is there to stop people entering duplicate info. 2) I'm unlikely to have access to the nodes terminal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815639/how-do-i-kill-a-flow-in-the-hospital

Comment: 1. Yes, but you defined the constraint on database level; which is very far in the execution (last step) actually. Maybe it's better to catch it earlier by using SpringBoot's `@UniqueConstraint` annotation on your entity, then when you use the same class as a request object (as an input parameter to your API) you can mark it with the `@Valid` annotation so that SpringBoot runs its validator against it. This way you catch things very early (before running the flow then targeting the database).

Comment: 2. You can write an API to kill a certain flow, but that's highly unrecommended; only an admin with access to node's terminal should be able to execute a `flow kill` command...at least in my opinion.

Comment: That is a potential idea, however, it requires that Spring has access to the database backing the node, which more often that not it doesn't.