# How Do I Kill A Flow In The Hospital?

Tags: corda

The [Hospital docs](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/node-flow-hospital.html#flow-hospital) says:

> you should be able to call killFlow with the UUID associated with the failing flow in the node’s log messages.

I obviously can't access the node logs from my RPC client.

So how am I supposed to get a list of flows in the hospital, find the reason why they were put in the hospital and kill the ones that I know will never complete?

Answer (score 1):

- Open the node terminal.
- Type `run stateMachinesSnapshot` to see all of the current flows.
- Get the ID of the hospitalized flow then run `flow kill` with that ID.
- Obviously, your RPC user must have the right permissions (see [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/shell.html#permissions)).

Comment: I don't have access to the node terminal. I'm running from an RPC client. Also, that command just shows the current flows and doesn't tell you which ones are hospitalised. I get a new transaction every second or so. How am I supposed to identify the hospitalised flow?

Comment: For some reason I remember that it shows a status field, if not; you can use Corda 4.6 new flow management API which allows you to query the flows and see their status. Read it about [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/whats-new-and-exciting-in-corda-4-6-9e41d1d40f31).

Comment: You can add an API to your RPC client that kills a flow by its ID, but still you need to find a way to get that ID.

Comment: `flowStatus` might just be Corda Enterprise because it isn't a valid node command in Corda OS 4.6

Comment: I guess you're right, I found it in Enterprise documentation (see [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.6/node/operating/querying-flow-data.html)), but not in OS.

Comment: What other choice do you have when it goes to the hospital and can't be recovered? If you can't kill it, it will stay forever spamming your logs every minute.